# Node.js pm2 Multi project startup？

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I have tow project.
The directory structure is as follows：
wwwnode
|-express
   |-bin
   |...
|-socketio
   |-index.js
   |...
|-process.json

'process.json' file configuration is as follows

```
{
  'apps':[
    {
        "name":"express",
        "script": "./bin/www",
        "cwd":"express",
        "watch": true
      },{
        "name":"socketio",
        "script": "socketio/index.js",
        "watch": true
    }
  ]
}
```

**cmd Console**

```
pm2 start process.json
```

but Second items appear in the browser access error 500，it's why?How to configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try to name your file `process.config.json`